# Cannot change permission inside pCloud drive folder

Tags: permissions, pcloud

I start using pcloud to keep my files sync on all of my computers (all are using ubuntu).
But when I tried to make one of the file executable it appear that I can't. I tried using `sudo chmod +x` but it doesn't change anything. I can't change any permission and that's anoying.
The file system of the drive is "fuse" if it helps.

Comment: The simple answer is that you can't. I am using the official pCloud executable ( https://www.pcloud.com/download-free-online-cloud-file-storage.html ), but it also does not allow changing file permissions.

Comment: Wondering if there is any news on that issue? I ran into the same error with a 'cargo build' command. A chmod command does not work neither. Best,
Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that this option to change the permissions is not possible at present, however, it is in our road map for future developments and we plan to implement that for sure!

The file system is exFAT and the GUI client makes all the files in pCloud Drive executable upon installation usually.

To get more information and guidance, you can always contact us at support@pcloud.com.

Comment: No. In Ubuntu all files have permission `0644/-rw-r--r--` and all directories `0755/drwxr-xr-x`. The mounted filesystem is reported as `pCloud.fs`.

Comment: Could you add a statement of affiliation to your post? Along the lines of this: https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/15631/57576 Thanks!